# How to word the results if a chi-square test of independence is significant, but no single post-hoc test is?

Tags: chi-squared-test, interpretation, post-hoc

I ran a chi-square test of independence on a 2-dimensional cross table, which resulted in a significant p-value.

I then ran post-hoc tests for all pairs of populations and adjusting by a bonferroni correction (I used the function `chisq.post.hoc` from the `fifer` package in R, if that matters).

There, no single pair was significant.

I understand that this can happen and is not out of the ordinary, but it's hard to put a justification for this result in writing. How would you word this situation correctly? I am thinking of something to the likes of:

> The significant p-value of the chi-squared test on the whole cross table suggests a dependency between the variables A and B. However, no specific group was found in the subsequent post-hoc tests, meaning that the overall dependency could not be linked to a specific pair of populations.

To me, this sounds correct but not helpful. Is there a better way to describe what the significant overall-test means if no single pair of population is found in the post-hoc tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a stab:

> A chi-squared test works by assuming that variables A and B are
>   independent and then looking for evidence that contradicts that
>   assumption. The stronger the overall evidence against independence,
>   the lower the p-value will be. In this case, the low p-value from the
>   test on the whole table suggests significant evidence for a dependency
>   between variables A and B. A follow-up post hoc analysis found that
>   the overall conclusion results from the accumulation of small amounts of
>   evidence from many cells in the table rather than from large
>   contributions of evidence from any particular cells.